# LazyHighchart and dated Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts, lazy-high-charts

Got a problem with highcharts. I have series with dated data (debit, month) and want to graph it. I can graph data (debit only), but when i want to add datetimes, there are 2 problems :

- x_axis data are bad displayed (00:00:00.00)(00:00:00.00), expecting month-year (08/2012)
- Tooltip told me "Invalid date"

```
def index
    @ops = getConstantOps()
    @js_data = []
    @ops.each { |f|
      tmp = [f.date_operation,f.debit]
      @js_data.push(tmp)
    }
    @h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
        f.options[:chart][:defaultSeriesType] = "area"
        f.x_axis({:type =>'datetime'} )
        f.series( :name=>'Ops', :data=>@js_data)
end
```

Ruby debug(@js_data) says

```
{--- !ruby/object:LazyHighCharts::HighChart
collection_filter: 
data:
- :name: Ops
  :data:
  - - 2010-07-08
    - 387.0
  - - 2010-08-09
    - 476.0
  - - 2010-09-08
    - 443.0}
```

So I need not to use "pointInterval" and "pointStart" because for some months I don't have any Ops. That's why I need a 2-dimension array as data param. I'm testing ruby/highcharts combination to build a company app, but quite a new on theese two tools.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

EDIT 11/11/2012 : 
After a fiw hours of work, it works! I've done a helper to do the crap cast.

Solution :

```
def getTimestamp(dateTime)
    return (DateTime.parse(dateTime.year.to_s + '-' + dateTime.month.to_s + '-01')).to_i * 1000
end
```

It look dirty for me (2 casts, dans hard day param). But didn't find cleaner way. If you have one, plz suggest ;).